# Determine if onclick was invoked via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input element which uses the `onclick` event to invoke some javascript function, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="blah" id="blah" onclick="doSomeFunction();"/>
```

My issue is this `onclick` event is also invoked by some vendor code elsewhere, like:

```
$('#blah').click();
```

I cannot modify the code that executes the `onclick` event of this element unfortunately, but can modify the `doSomeFunction()` function.

Is it possible to determine if the `onclick` event was invoked via javascript, or was an actual click?

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm needing to modify `doSomeFunction()` to remember a value if a user clicked on it. Since their code "clicks" on it also, I can't just modify `doSomeFunction()` to save the value when it's invoked, nor will adding a new function into `onclick=` work. I seem to be against a wall, unless I can determine if a click was an actual click.

Comment: $('#blah').click(); function is already bind with the DOM, so it doesn't require onclick method.

Comment: @lpradhap they use it to trigger the onclick event, which triggers other things to run. I originally just modified `doSomeFunction()` to save my value, but it gets run on page load, which defeats by attempts.

Comment: Can you modify the html to pass `event` into function? There will be some minor differences in event object that you can check for

Comment: can you onclick="doSomeFunction('clicked-true');" and try to check if this value is passed only to your specific function, if it works you can check if that value is true and execute your code.

Comment: have you tried using something like `mousedown` from jquery https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ instead of the html `onclick`? This may be able to tell the difference between a programmatic click and a user click.

Comment: @charlietfl that might be on the right (ie. easiest) track. It seems when it's programmically clicked, a different type of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pass in the `event` object you can check for some differences in properties like `clientX` or `clientY` and `isTrusted`.

Note I've never done this before but tested it in Firefox and Chrome

```js
function doSomeFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.isTrusted ? 'Manually clicked' : 'Clicked programatically');
  console.log('ClientX=', event.clientX)
}


$('button').click(function() {
  $('#blah').click()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="blah" id="blah" onclick="doSomeFunction(event);" />

<button>
Trigger a click
</button>
```

Comment: Any idea if a touch event (from a mobile) also contains `isTrusted`?

Comment: The browser will determine the `event` properties. Assume it would  be true for touch also assuming the browser has that property. I didn't even know that property existed until I compared the 2 events for this answer and saw they were different

Comment: I see, I'll do some experimentation then. Thank you.

Comment: From MDN: "**The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via dispatchEvent.**" -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted -- Seems this may in fact be a reliable way to determine if it was a real user click event. Very good stuff indeed!

Comment: May still need to verify it exists in some mobile browsers but I'm guessing it is fairly standard

Comment: Very true. I'll do some testing and make sure I get the same values.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="blah" id="blah" onclick="doSomeFunction('blahClick');"/>

function doSomeFunction(text){
  if (text == "blahClick") {
   //run your code. 
  }
}
```

note, if this works can you tick answered.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I believe this would always pass the same value 'blahClick' into the function - whether it's clicked literally or programmically.

Comment: ok.. thanks my understanding was that your trying exclude your script from some other function.